# Tips on how to improve a lung segmentation program

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, medical

I'm developing lung segmentation program in MATLAB, *not* being allowed to use any sort of machine learning, and ideally implementing all (or most) image processing methods I use, for an assignment.

Currently, it's mostly based on Otsu thresholding and morph. transformations and (kinda) good results look something like this: [Example 1 - Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS06T.png), [Example 1 - Segmented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuAA5.png),  [Example 2 - Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EFOm.png) and [Example 2 - Segmented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob6xE.png).

Not good cases look like this: [Example 3 - Segmented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSXrp.png) and actual failures look like this: [Example 4 - After Otsu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNXtD.png).

What king of processing (including pre or post) could I use to improve the lungs' outlines in good cases?

How can I correcly fill the mask in the not good scenario? (I've messed around with imfill and it didn't help much)

And, at last, is there a way to ensure that the lungs will always be a closed region after Otsu thresholding? (Failure case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try other auto  thresholding methods.  Print the histogram and where  the algorithm  picks  the  threshold  value to understand the reason  of failure.